# Can anyone tell me why my array is behaving inconsistently?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

This is my first non-trivial VBA program, and although I have used arrays before in various dialects of BASIC, and have spent the last three or four evenings poring over Walkenbach's 'Excel VBA for Dummies' I am baffled.

I expected to find that the value of one element of the array had been increased by one, and out of 475 runs the code has performed as expected just 449 times.  The other 26 runs produced one element increased by 2 instead.  To add to the weirdness, of the twelve elements that are accessed by this initial block of code only four of them ever exhibit this behaviour, the others returning 1s as expected.

If it would help I can post the two tables that the errant function uses, but I don't see how this can happen whatever the data is.

```
'UDF to roll a number of Dice of specified size and total them
  Function Dice(NoOfDice, DiceSize)
    Dice = 0
      For i = 1 To NoOfDice
        Dice = Dice + WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, DiceSize)
      Next
  End Function

'UDF to generate a skill from the MOS Table
  Function MOSSkill(ArmOfService, TechLevel)
    Roll = Dice(1, 6)
      If TechLevel = 2 Then Roll = Roll + 1 'TL-11 or less = 1; TL-12+ = 2
        MOSSkill = WorksheetFunction.VLookup((WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Roll, (Range(Cells(4, 2), Cells(10, 8))), ArmOfService, False)), (Range(Cells(9, 32), Cells(39, 33))), 2, False)
  End Function

Sub MercOne()

Randomize

Dim Merc(86)

45 For i = 1 To 86
     Merc(i) = 0
  Next

TechLevel = Dice(1, 2)

Roll = Dice(2, 6)
   If Merc(2) >= 6 Then Roll = Roll + 1
   If Merc(3) >= 5 Then Roll = Roll + 2
   If Roll < 5 Then GoTo 45

ArmOfService = Dice(1, 4)
    If ArmOfService = 4 Then
       ArmOfService = ArmOfService + 2
        Else: ArmOfService = ArmOfService + 1
    End If

'Array Check 1
  For i = 7 To 37
    Debug.Print Merc(i); ",";
  Next
    Debug.Print

Merc(MOSSkill(ArmOfService, TechLevel)) = Merc(MOSSkill(ArmOfService, TechLevel)) + 1

'Array Check 2
For i = 7 To 37
    Debug.Print Merc(i); ",";
  Next
    Debug.Print

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a probablility of 1/6 that when MOSSkill runs, it will increment Roll, and that affects the lookup.

So, when you access your array by

```
Merc(MOSSkill(ArmOfService, TechLevel))
```

and then increment

```
Merc(MOSSkill(ArmOfService, TechLevel)) + 1
```

there is a chance that the second one, will not refer to the same thing as the first one, so you increment the wrong one.

you need:

```
temp=MOSSkill(ArmOfService, TechLevel)
Merc(temp)=Merc(temp)+1
```

that way they'll always be the same

your code sometimes does this:
(I'm adding a +1 or +0 in the index since thats what MOSSkill does)

```
Merc(1)=Merc(1)+1;    //Merc(1+0)=Merc(1+0)+1
Merc(3)=Merc(2)+1;    //Merc(2+1)=Merc(2+0)+1
Merc(4)=Merc(3)+1;    //Merc(3+1)=Merc(3+0)+1
Merc(5)=Merc(5)+1;    //Merc(4+1)=Merc(4+1)+1
```

Like that. So in that case Merc(4) is 2

Comment: Thanks, I've just tried it.  Now, when it runs, it doesn't produce any 1s or 2s, just an empty array [?]

Comment: try dim temp as integer  maybe mosSkill is returning something else

Comment: and also Function MOSSkill(ArmOfService, TechLevel) As Integer   (in the declaration

Comment: It's occurred to me that TechLevel is set before the expression is evaluated, in the body of the Sub, and so will be the same for both sides.

Comment: And even so, if that was where the problem lay the expression could still only increase an element by 1, and not the two that I am getting in 5.5% of cases.

Comment: did you consider that it increased the same element by 1, twice?

Comment: Yes, but with only one pass through the code I couldn't work out how it might be doing it.  Studying the output in detail I know realise that there were two separate problems; the one I asked for help with above, but also the fact that the code was (usually) incrementing the wrong element.  I was confused because your suggestion only seemed to address the problem I hadn't known about, the mismatch of the elements, but it had somehow also solved my original problem.  That is why I accepted your answer, because it worked, although I must confess that I'm not sure why.  Thanks.

Comment: your code sometimes does Merc(1)=Merc(1)+1; Merc(3)=Merc(2)+1;Merc(4)=Merc(3)+1;  Merc(5)=Merc(5)+1;   Like that. So in that case Merc(4) is 2.

Comment: I can see that this would happen with my original code, as it progresses through the subsequent blocks of code (not yet written).  But, and this is the important point, as it stands the code (new or old) is only executed once.  Your example is of a case where the existing routine is executed more than once.